# Rails received invalid response to SSL Negotiation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, firefox, ubuntu

The second I run rails s I get the error from my title on my screen. I am using port -5432, Ubuntu, PostgreSQL and Firefox. I did not create this app I am learning code through modifying it and I haven't even modified it yet. Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is the database.yml

```
default: &default
adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  port: 5432

development:
  <<: *default
  database: test_development
```

Here is the server Error

```
2015-07-11 04:09:45 -0700: HTTP parse error, malformed request (): #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.>
2015-07-11 04:09:45 -0700: ENV: {"rack.version"=>[1, 3], "rack.errors"=>#<IO:<STDERR>>, "rack.multithread"=>true, "rack.multiprocess"=>false, "rack.run_once"=>false, "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"", "CONTENT_TYPE"=>"text/plain", "QUERY_STRING"=>"", "SERVER_PROTOCOL"=>"HTTP/1.1", "SERVER_SOFTWARE"=>"2.11.3", "GATEWAY_INTERFACE"=>"CGI/1.2"}
---


Started POST "/__better_errors/843c1a9e623e5260/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-11 04:09:45 -0700
```

Comment: can u say me which error message u r getting?

Comment: Can you add bit of a code? `server log`, `database.yml` would be helpful.

Comment: does anybody have a solution?

Comment: Proxy or forwarding request issues? Hard to say from the info here, and without knowing how you got to this point.'

Comment: Yeah lol... I don't even know how this issue came about. I'll email the repo owner and tell him about the issue. Maybe it's a bug on his end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got errors like "received invalid response to SSL negotiation: H" trying to boot a Rails app in development.

It turned out to be a mistake in database.yml, where I was setting the port to the wrong value (I was reading the wrong environment variable). So make sure the port is configured correctly.